# Redundant results when printing duplicates from an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

This is a small part of my code, where I'm printing the duplicates found in an array. The problem is that it prints each duplicate occurrence more than once. Ex. the array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,2,2) prints

> ```
> value 2 at position 1 is also at position 10
> value 2 at position 1 is also at position 11
> value 2 at position 10 is also at position 11
> ```

instead of just

> ```
> value 2 at position 1 is also at position 10
> value 2 at position 1 is also at position 11
> ```

```
    for(i = 0; i < num_count; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < num_count; j++) {
            if (num[i] == num[j]){
                printf("\nvalue %d at position %d is also at position %d", num[i], i, j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what do you want to achieve??

Comment: You have to remember which positions/values you have printed already.

Comment: What if value is at more than 2 positions? Which is what you are seeing I think.

Comment: @Rakkun Thanks, think I have an idea on what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowed to modify your array, consider removing a value from the array once you have identified it as a duplicate (e.g., set it to -1 or some other value outside your normal range of inputs).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you understand the problem with the code you've pasted, and ask for algorithm suggestions.

If cpp is allowed, you may consider using STL's Map, key is the number, and value is the number's index. Loop through the array once, as you loop through, check the elements' occurrence in the map first. If key already exist, output; otherwise, put this element and its index into the map.

Hope it helps.